# How do I change the properties of a DOM element based on a property of an adjacent field?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the background positioning for a label based on whether or not an adjacent checkbox is checked.

I figured out how to select adjacent fields with jQuery and I verified that this selector is indeed working:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'] + label")
```

But I can't figure out how to access the checkbox.

Here's what I have so far...

```
$("input[type='checkbox'] + label").click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-position", $("--adjacent checkbox here--").attr('checked') ? "bottom" : "top");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[type='checkbox'] + label").click(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.css("background-position", $th.prev().attr('checked') ? "bottom" : "top");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

jQuery's `prev()` method selects the immediate previous sibling if one exists.

Comment: There is also next and siblings as well.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  I thought that `prev()` and `next()` only selected the previous and next elements that were satisfied by the selector.  I didn't realize they could be used to grab any DOM element at all.  But that definitely works.

Comment: @Steve - Glad it worked. Yeah, those (and others) are traversal methods that actually crawl the DOM for you from a starting point. Very handy. :o)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I understand completely why that works.  The object passed through `this` holds a reference to the DOM object, and has no direct connection to the selector that was used to get that object.  I should have thought of that.